# Making it so the first time you run the app you have to put in a code that can only be used once

Tags: android

In trying to make a app and the first time you run it you would need to put in a code thats 12 digits I would have maybe 10000 diffrent codes but when someone uses a code it can not be used again
PS: The app is for android

Comment: You will have to store the entered codes on your app's server and then each time user enters a code fire a request to the server to check if code is unique or not.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari What? Why is a server required? How does your comment contribute in ensuring it only runs once ?

Comment: Welcome, please provide some code you have so we can help you. Question is too general at the moment. In general you would some kind of database (locally on Android or on server) to store used pins.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to answer that part. So to check if app is run first time or no just you can use SharedPreferences. In shared preferences you just set a boolean variable to true when app is run and a code has been entered and then on each run check if that variable is true or false, if true then dont show enter code, else show enter code.

Comment: See, either server or cloud based database storage needs to be used to store all codes entered so that no code is repeated.

Comment: And since you say there can be upto 10k codes so storing them locally is memory costly. Hence, use a server or cloud db.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari 10K is a small database. Not to mention you just assumed he would have a list of all the codes, instead of, for example, validating them.

Comment: Alright, clear this then I'll go ahead. What do you mean when you say this? -> "when someone uses a code it can not be used again". I assumed you mean the code must be unique amongst all codes ever entered.

Comment: yes it would be unique so if someone uses the code to gain access to the app and then someone else puts in the same code to gain acces he will not gain access to the app and it would just say something like "Invalid Code"

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a **Login.**

When the application is `started`, show the PIN **request** to the user.

Then, **validate** his PIN and **save** it (database, shared preferences, server etc.). Let's say you decide to save it locally in SQLite.

The next time he opens the App, **check** if there is a PIN in the database and **validate** it again, if everything is alright, `start` the next `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Put all the codes in a server-side database
2) In the app, let the user enter a code and send it to your server
3) Validate the code. If successful, remove that code and generate and return a unique accesstoken.
4) Store the accesstoken in the app and validate it with the server on subsequent app usage to gain access.